# Java - How to extract information from many XML files in a directory and export it to an excel file

Tags: java, xml, extract

I am trying to get information from many *xml files* in a directory.

How can I get specific information from each one and send it to an *excel file*, in java?

```
file 1.xml
file 2.xml
file 3.xml

*********

**file.csv** or .**xls** with the information of the 'n' files XML
```

Comment: What exactly are your trying to extract, all the contents in the file Question is not clear, so essentially you want to parse xml files and use tags as a constraints and append that data to an xlsx file.

Comment: Yes, the structure of my XML files is as follows:
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<File>
  <Cnbv_NumeroOffic> 554433 </ Cnbv_NumeroOffices>
  <Cnbv_NumeroDocument> AB / 983 </ Cnbv_NumeroDocument>
  <Cnbv_SolicitudSiara> DASD / DHF / 44526 </ Cnbv_SolicitudSiara>
  <Cnbv_Folio> 32345 </ Cnbv_Folio>
</ File>

I have approximately 30 files, and I want to export the tag Cnbv_NumeroOffic, Cnbv_NumeroDocument and Cnbv_Folio to an exel file

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Your question is too broad and will eventually be downvoted and closed. Did you try anything? What is your specific problem? Show us your code and error messages, if there are any. You should read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

there are several libraries on Java that can help you to do so.

For instance, for getting information from XML you can use [dom4j](https://dom4j.github.io/) and extract the specific information make use of the query language XPATH, supported by the library ([examples](https://github.com/dom4j/dom4j/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide)). And to read all the XML files form a directory, Java 8 has an easy way of achieving that.

```
Files.list(Paths.get("/path/to/xml/files"))
        .map(YourXMLParser::parse)
        .forEach(XLSExporter::export);
```

where parse method would have the signature:

```
public MyDataBean parse(Path path) {
    InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(Path);
    SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder(inputStream);
    ... <-- Making use of SAX for instance and return the read data in a custom Bean (MyDataBean)
}
```

As **Files.list()** method return **Stream** you can take advantage of that to use *map* and *forEach*.

Once you have the information from each XML files to you can export to XLS using the most used library in Java for it: [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)

I hope it can help.